# Replace a string in databinder.eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my .aspx code i have the following element

```
<asp:Image ID="GalleryImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ProductImage") %>'                                             />
```

The value returned for this is a image URl from a content delivery network with a sample url like `'http://cdn.xyz.com'`

I want to convert the url to `'https://cdn.xyz.com'`

I tried to do `ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ProductImage").Replace("http","https") %>'` which doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Where your `ProductImage` come from? Don't you want to change it there? on `.cs` (code behind) side?

Comment: @teovankot, i dont have access to the code behind. It is sitting inside a dll

Comment: not sure, but have you tried this: `((string)Eval("ProductImage")).Replace("http","https")`?

Comment: `doesn't seem to work` is not a very good description of the issue. Please remember to include details about exactly how your code behaves compared to how you expect it to behave. Does it cause an error/exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can handle it like:

```
<%# ((string)Eval("ProductImage")).Replace("http", "https") %>
```

And if your string can be `Null`

```
<%# ((string)Eval("ProductImage") ?? string.Empty).Replace("http", "https") %>
```

And it will be:

```
<asp:Image ID="GalleryImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# ((string)Eval("ProductImage") ?? string.Empty).Replace("http", "https") %>'
```

OR if you are sure your string will not be `Null` in any case.

```
<asp:Image ID="GalleryImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# ((string)Eval("ProductImage")).Replace("http", "https") %>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you might have to first convert to `String` for `Replace` to work:

```
<asp:Image ID="GalleryImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ProductImage").ToString().Replace("http","https") %>'
```

`Eval` returns `object` and `Replace` wouldn't work on `object`. You need to `Cast/Convert` the returned `object` into `String` first and then use the `Replace` method on that `String`.